# What is the difference between encodeWithSelector and encode?

Tags: solidity, delegatecall, abiencoderv2, abi.encodewithsignature

I've been messing around with the `abi.encode...` functions and I think I have a good grasp of the differences, except `abi.encode` and `abi.encodeWithSelector`. Because, they give similar but slightly different results, so I'm not sure when to use one or the other.

```
  abi.encodeWithSelector(bytes4(keccak256("add(uint256,uint256)")), 10,10);
  abi.encode(bytes4(keccak256("add(uint256,uint256)")), 10, 10);
```

The output of encodeWithSelector is

```
0x771602f7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
```

and the output of encode is

```
0x771602f700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
```

and when I use delegatecall the return value of encodeWithSelector is 20, as expected, but encode is 42949672960

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal `abi.encode` encodes values according to the abicoder. A `bytes4` value is padded to 32 bytes

```
0x771602f700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
  ^ first 32 byte word                                            ^ second 32 byte word                                           ^ third 32 byte word
```

Using `abi.encodeWithSelector` allows you to correctly encode function calldata by adding a 4 bytes selector at the beginning (which can also be accessed using `add.selector`). The encoding becomes

```
0x771602f7000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
  ^ 4 bytes selector
          ^ first 32 byte word                                            ^ second 32 byte word
```

When using encode, the function reads the parameters from calldata with their expected offset. When incorrectly encoding with `abi.encode`, the first parameter (first 32 bytes after the 4 bytes selector) are 0, the second 32 bytes read `a00000000`, because of how the calldata is shifted now, as can be seen here (the third word is simply ignored):

```
0x771602f700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000a
  ^ 4 bytes selector
          ^ first 32 byte word                                            ^ second 32 byte word                                           ^ third 32 byte word
```

0xa00000000 is 42949672960 encoded. So `abi.encode` essentially returns the result of `add(0, 42949672960)`

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But then in what situation would I use encode?

Comment: It's often used for calculating the keccak256 hash of some data (it requires bytes as input). Or when sending arbitrary data (to another contract for example) it can be encoded as bytes and then decoded later. This is for example done for L1 <-> L2 message passing.

Comment: thank you for the clarification